# pass url data to new site on 301 permanent redirect

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, url-rewriting, url-routing

I have enabled the 301 redirect on IIS 6 for my old site,the option for passing the query string is enabled in the IIS as mentioned in this article.

http://www.developerfusion.com/code/4678/permanent-301-redirect-with-querystring-in-iis/

My old site is webforms based while my new site is asp.net mvc 3 based.

I get the query string on the redirected site,but having problem for one specific url redirect.

The redirection for this link http://oldsite.com/blog/123-this-is-a-title.aspx goes to 
http://newsite.com/blogpost.aspx?blogpostid=888&/blogpost.aspx.I loose the title from my old site.

I need the title of the post from the old site to come in my new site in the url,so that the custom route in my asp.net mvc apps can read the title from the url and get the blog post id for the title.

Please let me know why i am not getting the title of the post on my new site when redirect happens and how to get the title from the old url to my new sites url.

Thanks.
S.

Answer (score 0):

I think the querystring is incorrect. It should be it the form of

```
http://server/path/?name1=value1&name2=value2 see [wikipeadia][1] or [w3c][2]
```

The title hasn't got a name tag. It should be

```
http://newsite.com/blogpost.aspx?blogpostid=888&title=/blogpost.aspx
```